# why Google play services is not found?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

i can't add google-play-services_lib to project

and  google-play-services_lib  not found in extras or add-ons

i install google-play-services from sdk manager

the problem still appare in com.google.android.gms that is

The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved

Comment: did you follow these instructions? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: Did you delete Google play services anytime soon from eclipse and checked the option, "Delete project contents on disk(cannot be undone)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where exactly are you looking for Google Play Services?

After you have installed it via SDK Manager, look for it in your SDK folder extras/google/google_play_services

You have to import it first in your IDE and then include in your project as a library project.